# Fetch nth row after mth row in mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch some particular row after I fetch all rows from table 'user' . 'user' table has 10 records like this

```
1 . ABCD
2 . hfdff
3 . uiyuiyoy
4 . uytitito
5 . piooioi
6 . GXX jhjkhh
7 . GXX uyyto
8 . GXX upupu
9 . tytuyur
10 . zvsfsgsg
```

So I want to show results like this

```
1 . ABCD
2 . hfdff
3 . uiyuiyoy
4 . uytitito
5 . piooioi
6 . tytuyur
7 . zvsfsgsg 
8 . GXX jhjkhh
9 . GXX uyyto
10 . GXX upupu
```

**I want to fetch records that starts with GXX at the last . Can it be done?** Can anyone tell me how to achieve this ? what will be the query for this? Please help .

Comment: Add `ORDER BY columnname` at the end of your SELECT.

Comment: What if you have `ABCD10` where should it be in output?

Comment: before GXX ABCD . I meant to say I want to fetch all GXX records at last

Comment: Adjust the sample data, it could need some more difficulties. (Like 'ABCD10', and 'XYZ ABCD1'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case..when` expression with `substr()` function :

`order by case when substring(str,1,3) = 'GXX' then 1 else 0 end, str`

this puts values starting with `GXX` at the bottom, but if you exactly order according to your desired output, prefer using this, rather :

`order by case when substring(str,1,3) = 'GXX' then 1 else 0 end,
          case when substring(str,5,1) = 'u' then str else 'z' end desc`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0b902fc773d131cf97704bb465381288)</kbd>

Comment: it worked for me but I am using SQL server so I changed substr to substring

Comment: well I converted from MySQL to SQL Server @Maximious

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY columnname ASC` at the end of your SELECT

Comment: I did this but problem is some user has their name starting with T . then results like this ABCD , ABCD1 , ABCD3 , ABCD4 , ABD5 , GXX ABCD , GXX ABCD1 , GXX ABCD2 , Tgdjggjdg like this . I want to fetch records that are starting with GXX at last

Answer (score 0):

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  This is handy in this situation:

```
order by (col like 'GXX%'),  -- put these last
         col
```